# Bubble Sort with G++

Tags: c++, linux, algorithm, g++, bubble-sort

I am simply trying to figure out how many times an item is swapped using bubble sort.

When I implement it on Windows, it works flawlessly. But implementing it on Linux with g++, the output is completely different and I am going crazy trying to figure out the bug.

Here is my bubbleSort function

```
int bubbleSort(string s){
int num = 0;

// Bubble sort string and count inversions on each swap
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < s.length() - 1; j++) {
        if(s[j] > s[j+1]) {
            swap(s[j], s[j+1]);
            num++;
        }
    }
}
return num;
}
```

Can anyone see anything wrong with this code which might be giving me problems between Windows and Linux?

Test input:
GCAD

Should return 6, but G++ is returning 10

Comment: No. What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: What's the output on each system? What strings are you passing in?

Comment: Does the program result in a sorted string? Or does it fail even worse than that? Can you print intermediate steps (say, value of `s` when `num%10==0`).

Comment: This is a long shot... but could it be that you have different character encodings? Does the answer change if you use `s.charAt(j)` rather than `s[j]` to access the jth element?

Comment: By swap, are you referring to std::swap function? Maybe try swapping s[j] and s[j+1] manually.

Comment: @Joni I added some test data. Still no luck with these options.

Comment: Please learn -on Linux- how to use the `gdb` debugger after having compiled with  `g++ -Wall -g`

Comment: How are you entering your string? Could it be that you are using `fgets` and are silently including the carriage return? Or some such. EXACTLY how do you call this function?

Comment: See my updated answer - adding a newline `'\n'` character to the end of the string does indeed result in `num=10`. "The problem is in the line of code you did not show". Wouldn't be the first time...

Comment: You should also realize a traditional bubble-sort does not repeatedly scan to the end of the sequence. As each item is "bubbled" to the end, the next iteration is no longer concerned with reaching that element and therefore reduce the loop by one. In short, change the `j` limit to be `j < s.length() - (i+1)`. You should integrate a `cmp` counter in this as well (just inside the beginning of the `j` loop before `if` block), and see the difference in the number of comparisons between what you have, and what I described. Swaps aren't the dominant expense of sorting; comparisons  are.

Answer (score 3):

I modified your code to give a complete working program:

```
#include <iostream>

int bubbleSort(std::string s) {
  int num = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < s.length() - 1; j++) {
      if(s[j] > s[j+1]) {
        std::swap(s[j], s[j+1]);
        num++;
        std::cout << "num is " << num << " and string is " << s << "\n";
      }
    }
  }
}

int main(void) {
  bubbleSort("ZWQM");
}
```

Compiled it on a 64 bit Linux machine with `g++`. Ran it. Result:

```
num is 1 and string is WZQM
num is 2 and string is WQZM
num is 3 and string is WQMZ
num is 4 and string is QWMZ
num is 5 and string is QMWZ
num is 6 and string is MQWZ
```

Six iterations, and string is sorted. Please confirm that this *exact* program does not produce *this exact output* for you... and tell us what it does do.

**EDIT** I found a way to get the answer `10`! I added a newline character to the string.

```
bubbleSort("ZWQM\n");
```

results in

```
num is 1 and string is WZQM

num is 2 and string is WQZM

num is 3 and string is WQMZ

num is 4 and string is WQM
Z
num is 5 and string is QWM
Z
num is 6 and string is QMW
Z
num is 7 and string is QM
WZ
num is 8 and string is MQ
WZ
num is 9 and string is M
QWZ
num is 10 and string is
MQWZ
```

Note how the carriage return is messing with the output as it "bubbles down" to the first character position. I am now 99% sure that the difference you observed relates to how you get your string into the program - and that Windows and Linux treat the end of line differently.

Comment: @Floris My output seems to be wrong: num is 1 and string is ADABEC
num is 2 and string is AADBEC
num is 3 and string is AABDEC
num is 4 and string is AABDCE
Eum is 5 and string is AABDC
Eum is 6 and string is AABCD
DEm is 7 and string is AABC
CDE is 8 and string is AAB
BCDEis 9 and string is AA
ABCDEs 10 and string is A

Comment: What input are you using? Is this with exactly the program I gave? I hard-wired the input to be "ZWQM" but you seem to have started with a different string?...

Comment: It seems as if the characters in the string change (and have a space in them) in your example. Your "swap" code is somehow broken. `AABC CDE` becomes `AAB BCDE` becomes `AA ABCDE`? When the letter swaps with the space, its ASCII value decreases by 1?? Show your `swap` function.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop terminating conditions should be modified in order to carry out unnecessary comparisons as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length()-1; i++) {         
    for(int j = 0; j < s.length() - i - 1; j++) {
        if(s[j] > s[j+1]) {
            swap(s[j], s[j+1]);
            num++;
        }
    }
}
```

As after each iteration, the last element is always sorted.

Comment: How does the existing loop access out of bounds array?

Comment: I have tried this. As well as fifty other syntax. No luck, still get the same results.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal it doesn't but it runs *thru* the nullchar terminator, which is *bad*. `0x00` is "less" than any non-null char, and thus it swaps the values, and in the process loses a char with each iteration (on the other side of the now-moved terminator). Bubblesort should be done from **1** thru **(len-1)**, and access elements `s[j-1]` against `s[j]`. The OP is close, just the wrong indexing.

Comment: I'm sorry I must be missing something. But how is the null terminator accessed? Eg if the string is "abcd", length = 4, max value of j = 2 (< length-1), hence max value of j+1 = 3, so j+1 accesses only upto 'd' character.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal actually, you didn't miss anything on that; I did. When looking at your code I didn't see the ` - 1` hanging on the end. With that it should work. I'll build it on my clang rig and let you know what it reports with your test string. You're not hallucinating; I was =P. Too late to be answering SO questions.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal I get 6 on my clang rig as well. With modifications strikingly similar to Floris answer.